# Adding Shortcode tag in the widget area

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to add a shortcode tag in the sidebar/widget.

I am able to get the required function if I add the code in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

My problem is that I am searching for a way I can do this from the plugins files itself without affecting any of the theme files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which plugin is this for? More information might help you get a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of creating your own [*Functionality Plugin*](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/functionality-plugins-vs-themes--wp-26314). Everything that is theme-independent should go in your own set of plugins. In this case, it would be simply:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Add text shortcode to widgets
 */
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Upload the file to the plugins folder and activate. You can have hundreds of plugins like this, if the code is solid, there's no problem on doing it and you can easily enable/disable custom functionality of the site.

Read more at WPSE: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031) and [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160)